# it is possible to retrieve the document / file using browser cache entry information when file not in cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

> i'm working in mvc4, c# web application. I know when image file is sent to the client browser, it is converted into some other format. That is understandable by browser due to security in transmission. My question is, I am viewing secured document in my project, for security purpose I changed the pdf document to image file and display it in client browser (conversions are done at server side)also I disabled cache information to no-cache but when I type "about:cache" in browser address bar, it shows list of url that was being accessed in browser. When i click on any one url, that redirected to some other page that shows cache entry information like below.

Cache entry information

key:    http://localhost:21638/WebFileViewer/DocumentViewer.axd/documents/f829f43e-3019-4517-98b2-03404e55f62d/pages/14?dpi=196&_=1424147788943

fetch count:    1
last fetched:   2015-02-17 10:06:53
last modified:  2015-02-17 10:06:36
expires:    1970-01-01 05:30:00
Data size:  325919 B
Security:   This document does not have any security info associated with it.
request-method:     GET
response-head:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0 
Date: Tue, 17 Feb 2015 04:36:36 
GMT X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
 Pragma: no-cache, no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store 
Expires: -1 
Content-Type: application/json; 
charset=utf-8 
Content-Length: 325919

00000000:  7b  22  77  69  64  74  68  22  3a  31  36  36  36  2c  22  68  {"width":1666,"h
00000010:  65  69  67  68  74  22  3a  32  31  35  36  2c  22  69  6d  61  eight":2156,"ima
00000020:  67  65  44  61  74  61  22  3a  22  69  56  42  4f  52  77  30  geData":"iVBORw0
00000030:  4b  47  67  6f  41  41  41  41  4e  53  55  68  45  55  67  41  KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA
00000040:  41  42  6f  49  41  41  41  68  73  43  41  59  41  41  41  42  ABoIAAAhsCAYAAAB
00000050:  39  46  2b  34  72  41  41  41  41  41  58  4e  53  52  30  49  9F+4rAAAAAXNSR0I
00000060:  41  72  73  34  63  36  51  41  41  41  41  52  6e  51  55  31  Ars4c6QAAAARnQU1
00000070:  42  41  41  43  78  6a  77  76  38  59  51  55  41  41  41  41  BAACxjwv8YQUAAAA
00000080:  4a  63  45  68  5a  63  77  41  41  44  73  4d  41  41  41  37  JcEhZcwAADsMAAA7
00000090:  44  41  63  64  76  71  47  51  41  41  50  2b  6c  53  55  52  DAcdvqGQAAP+lSUR
000000a0:  42  56  48  68  65  37  4c  30  74  6c  44  52  4e  73  58  61  BVHhe7L0tlDRNsXa
000000b0:  4e  52  43  4b  52  53  43  51  53  69  55  51  69  6b  55  67  NRCKRSCQSiUQikUg
000000c0:  6b  34  67  67  63  45  6f  6e  45  6e  4c  57  51  53  43  51  k4ggcEonEnLWQSCQ
000000d0:  53  69  55  51  69  2b  52  79  76  51  79  4c  76  72  2f  64  SiUQi+RyvQyLvr/d
000000e0:  77  58  38  38  4a  34  73  6d  73  2f  35  37  75  36  64  6c  wX88J4sms/57u6dl
000000f0:  37  72  56  77  7a  55  35  57  56  47  52  6b  5a  2b  52  66  7rVwzU5WVGRkZ+Rf
00000100:  52  31  66  4f  64  4c  79  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  R1fOdLyIiIiIiIiI
00000110:  69  49  69  49  69  49  76  4b  53  47  41  67  53  45  52  45  iIiIiIvKSGAgSERE
00000120:  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  46  35  55  51  77  RERERERERERF5UQw
00000130:  45  69  59  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  EiYiIiIiIiIiIiIi
00000140:  49  76  43  67  47  67  6b  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  IvCgGgkRERERERER
00000150:  45  52  45  52  45  52  46  34  55  41  30  45  69  49  69  49  ERERERF4UA0EiIiI
00000160:  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  76  69  6f  45  iIiIiIiIiIiIvioE
00000170:  67  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  47  gERERERERERERERG
00000180:  52  46  38  56  41  6b  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  RF8VAkIiIiIiIiIi
00000190:  49  69  49  69  49  79  49  74  69  49  45  68  45  52  45  52  IiIiIyItiIEhERER
000001a0:  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  4f  52  46  4d  52  41  ERERERERERORFMRA
000001b0:  6b  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  4c  kIiIiIiIiIiIiIiL
000001c0:  79  6f  68  67  49  45  68  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  52  45  yohgIEhERERERERE
000001d0:  52  45  52  45  52  65  56  45  4d  42  49  6d  49  69  49  69  REREReVEMBImIiIi
000001e0:  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  49  69  4c  77  6f  42  6f  4a

whether i can retrieve the image file using the above information even if the image not in the cache?

Comment: your link redirects us to your local machine...

Comment: that's the url,when i click that url the remaining information in my question appears

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking.